# Get Data from Json String using List<t> in android

Tags: java, android, json

I am fetching data from Json String using `List<t>`.
I am able to get data of Question & QId but Options is json string inside json string. So I am being confused about how to get those data.
**My sample code to get data :**

```
Test[] placelist = gson.fromJson(result, Test[].class);
List<Test> lList = Arrays.asList(placelist);
Test obj = lList.get(i);
obj.getQuestion();
```

Test is Java Class file which contains method to get & set data.

**My Json String:**

```
 [
    {
        "Question": "Are you inclined to",
        "QId": "2",
        "Options": [
            {
                "Option": "Argue or debate issues",
                "OptionId": "4"
            },
            {
                "Option": "Avoid arguments",
                "OptionId": "5"
            },
            {
                "Option": "Swutch topics",
                "OptionId": "6"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Question": "Are you more likely to trust",
        "QId": "3",
        "Options": [
            {
                "Option": "Yourself",
                "OptionId": "7"
            },
            {
                "Option": "Reason",
                "OptionId": "8"
            },
            {
                "Option": "Feeling",
                "OptionId": "9"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Question": "Would you say that you",
        "QId": "4",
        "Options": [
            {
                "Option": "Make decisions easily",
                "OptionId": "10"
            },
            {
                "Option": "Find difficulties to make decision",
                "OptionId": "11"
            },
            {
                "Option": "Wait for some conclusions",
                "OptionId": "12"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Test Class:**

```
public class Test{

    private String Question;
    private String Option;

    public Test(String Question, String Option) {
        this.Question= Question;
        this.Option= Option;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String Question) {
        this.Test= Question;
    }

    public void setOption(String Option) {
        this.Option= Option;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return this.Question;
    }

    public String getOption() {
        return this.Option;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what to use instead of `setOption()` & `getOption()` to get Options.
Please help me to get data of Options.

Comment: Please post the contents of Test, this will determine how to access the values in options.

Comment: check updated post. I am not sure what to write for options.

Comment: you have also make class for options

Comment: yes, but I am not sure what to use there. by using 'getOption()'. I am not getting data.

Comment: for that you have to also return arraylist for options.

Comment: your mean different arraylist?

Comment: any other better solution to get data from above json string ?

Comment: You have static option number means All question have 3 option or change later on...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of immediately obvious problems with your Test class:

1. "Option" is "Options" in your JSON, you need to rename or annotate this.
2. Options is a String type in your Test class but is actually an array in the JSON data. You will need to create an Option class and change the type in the Test class to List<Option>.

Comment: So, what changes I will need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use gson in order to get the data. 
Steps:

```
1. Create the test class such that it has question,id as string 
and Option as a list of options, and Test is going to be a list of Test
2. Use @SerializedValue in order to map the fields correctly.
3. Refer to :
```

[this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/json-parsing-with-gson/) for an idea as to how to use gson